# Nifi - ignore(or remove) the first digit of JSON

Tags: json, function, line, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a JSON with a variable that I need to ignore the first digit.

```json
{
  "destinatarioDTO" : {
    "cnpj" : "01377071000170"
  }
}
```

I got the variable with the EvaluateJsonPath.

I need to transform the result `01377071000170` into `1377071000170` (remove the first digit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a **JoltTransformJSON** processor along with the following spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "destinatarioDTO": {
        "len_cnpj": "=size(@(1,cnpj))",
        "cnpj": "=substring(@(1,cnpj),1,@(1,len_cnpj))" // extract the value starting from the second character(one with the index 1) till the end of the string
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "destinatarioDTO": {
        "len_cnpj": "" // get rid of newly generated, auxiliary attribute
      }
    }
  }
]
```